# Undefined variable: errors (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ninjatv\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I tried to setup route for the admin middleware at routes.php

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
});
```

and in AdminController I set up function for index as below:-

```
    public function index(){
        return view('backend.index');
    }
```

But the problems is my path xxx/admin change to xxx/login automatically. It should be display the login page but it display Undefined variable: errors

Comment: are you customized login.blade.php file?

Comment: and also make sure you passed errors in your login controller authentication check function

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Below route will redirect you to the login page if the session is not authenticated. If you are a valid logged in user then it will stay on this route.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
});
```

If the route is redirected this wouldn't call this method

```
public function index(){
   return view('backend.index');
}
```

> The redirected route now call the login method. Which will ideally be
>   expected to display your login page. In your case, it is happening correctly but the problem is you are getting errors as an undefined variable. You need to pass errors variable to auth.login view, just like below:-

```
 public function index(){
    return view(
        'auth.login',
        ["errors" => "call here your method that will give error"]);
 }
```

Refer here if you need to know more about methods of finding the error of submitted form or we can say validation: - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation